# MyAllSearch.com Threat Hijack?

Tags: google-chrome, virus, malware, search-engines, hijack

It seems like Iv'e been infected with some kind of chrome hijacker which changes my homepages to myallsearch.com.

I removed the file from the system with SpyHunter, but after logging in again into chrome, the system got the infection again.
I really have no clue what to do in such cases and I do not have any knowledge regarding digital security, I would appreciate any suggestion on this problem

Anyone seen this before? Is it even safe to use?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One more hint, with which I some times ago after several even successful malware cleaning rounds finally got rid of one of those nasty browser hijackers -> check all the Icons with which you open the browsers -> Properties -> Object -> and clean all suspectable/strange extra definitions after the .exe .

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the thread Ramhound linked, you may also want to look into resetting your Chrome's settings. Doing so will stop your homepage from sticking on "MyAllSearch". This can be done from "Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Reset Settings".

You will also want to clear any extensions that may be present, as something like MyAllSearch is likely to have installed some unwanted extensions that are probably redownloading things in the background. This can be accessed by going to "Settings -> Extensions" and clearing anything you don't recognize or don't want.